# Custom bang! method and Rails validation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, validation, active-record

I have a model called booking.

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :charges
  def charge!
    raise "Not active" if !active?

    c = charges.create()
    c.charge!
  end
end
```

However I feel this is not optimal. For example, it would be nice to integrate the activeness checking into Rails' own validation system.

Another example is that Rails build-in `create` or `save` are not used:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :charges
  def charge!
    raise "Not active" if !active?

    compute_charges!
  end
end
```

However I want the bang! method to imitate so that it feels like it went through validation and persistence. Is there a more elegant way to do this?